# Should the trusted Root CA be a part of the certificate chain?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, jks

I'm setting up 2-way SSL communication between services on different hosts. Let's say I have my own CA called A. A is trusted by all of my services through a centralized jks. Now let's say I have certificate B signed by A. When services send the certificate should they be sending the entire chain B - A, or just B? I believe both tend to work with most implementations.

I tried to find canonical information about this online, but I'm coming up with nothing.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What software is used to validate the certificate? What information is the validating entity fed apart from the certificate? (a [mcve], perhaps)

Comment: The question is more about the standard than specific software. The validating entity is fed the cert and it knows it trusts the CA.

Comment: If it's about what standards say, then related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81972/what-part-of-tls-specifies-how-to-verify-a-certificate-chain

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [tls - Validating an SSL certificate chain according to RFC 5280: Am I understanding this correctly? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72077/validating-an-ssl-certificate-chain-according-to-rfc-5280-am-i-understanding-th/72085#72085):

> the server should send the exact chain that is to be used; the server
> is explicitly allowed to omit the root CA, but that's all.

Reference ([RFC 5246 - TLS v1.2, sec. 7.4.2. - Server Certificate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2)):

> certificate_list
>
> This is a sequence (chain) of certificates. The sender's
> certificate MUST come first in the list. Each following certificate
> MUST directly certify the one preceding it. Because certificate
> validation requires that root keys be distributed independently, the
> self-signed certificate that specifies the root certificate
> authority MAY be omitted from the chain, under the assumption that
> the remote end must already possess it in order to validate it in
> any case.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind the trusted root CA is that it is trusted. Would you expect the browser to trust anything sent by the server just because it includes a root CA? No!

Therefore the root CA must be already at the client and must be trusted there. It should not be included in the certificate chain by the server, but if you do it anyway browsers will simply ignore it.

Comment: I have done some experiments: create a new Root CA, derive a SSL certificate from it, then configure apache's SSL settings, if I don't append the Root CA certificate to the SSL certificate file, then Chrome will not let me access the website, if I included it, then Chrome will give me a security warning and give me a choice to continue accessing the website with risks.  The point is, for a non-prebuilt-in Root CA, including the Root CA into the SSL certificate would helps users who are not care of security, otherwise, they can not even access the website.

Comment: @osexp2003: That's not how root CA should be used in the first place. The idea of a root CA is that it is is __already trusted__ by the client and thus can be used to verify the trust chain. In this case the client already has it. If a client would simply trusts arbitrary root CA delivered by the server then man in the middle attacks would be trivial - the attacker would just have to use its own root CA. If you want to help users which do not care about security just use plain HTTP - instead of teaching users that they can ignore certificate errors.

Comment: I understand. I am just trying to say, in real world, when a user just WANT to access the websites which certificate is not signed by a trusted source, then website must include such a should-not-be-included root ca certificate into its certificate chain, otherwise, at least Chrome will not let the user access the website, not even providing the "ignore security risk and continue" option.