# ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3833) in python ssl library

Tags: python, ssl, azure-iot-hub

so I was working with verify a X509 certificate to my IoT Hub in order to send/receive message from my application. However it keeps throwing out the `ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3833)` error.

I have the correct certificate, private key and the pass phrase. So I went over to the python github to check out what does the error means, and the line 3833 in the _ssl.c file means

```
r = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(self->ctx,
        PyBytes_AS_STRING(certfile_bytes));
    PySSL_END_ALLOW_THREADS_S(pw_info.thread_state);
    if (r != 1) {
        if (pw_info.error) {
            ERR_clear_error();
            /* the password callback has already set the error information */
        }
        else if (errno != 0) {
            ERR_clear_error();
            PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_OSError);
        }
        else {
            _setSSLError(NULL, 0, __FILE__, __LINE__); <--- THIS IS LINE 3833
        }
        goto error;
    }
```

Does that means my certificate is wrong? My certificate currently is the location like C:/Certificate/MyCertName.pfx
Thank you for reading and any helps is appreciated!

Source of the _ssl.c in python 3.7.4: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.4/Modules/_ssl.c

Comment: To get the source corresponding to your copy of Python, you need to check not the tip of the branch but the tag/commit corresponding to your specific release. `sys.version` has that info.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Hi, thanks for pointing that out! I do look into the wrong file, my version is v3.7.4, I've updated the question, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file` ([which is a part of OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file.html)) returned an error code and neither of the two typical cases describe the situation, so Python's code cannot tell you more about it.

So the only lead is to check what exactly that function receives and read its documentation (and source code if that's not enough) to try to figure out why it fails. If that's not enough, you'll have to run the process under a C debugger to check the same in vivo.

---

My (blind) guess is that the certificate file might be of an incorrect/unsupported format/cipher, or not contain [the correct certificate chain as required by the TLS standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945244/should-the-trusted-root-ca-be-a-part-of-the-certificate-chain/34948339#34948339). Specifically, the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file.html) says:

> `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file()` loads a certificate chain from
>   `file` into `ctx`. The certificates must be in PEM format and must be
>   sorted starting with the subject's certificate (actual client or
>   server certificate), followed by intermediate CA certificates if
>   applicable, and ending at the highest level (root) CA.

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, it does because of my certificate is in PFX format, I converted it into PEM format and everything works like a charm! Thank you for the helps!!